# Maximum call depth exceeded

Tags: lua, stack-overflow

I am using an integration engine **Iguana** by iNTERFACEWARE that uses Lua as the scripting language.

I have  a function that recursively calls itself to split the string based on number of words i.e if I huge text chunk is passed it is divided into chunks of 80 words let's say. Now this function works just fine upto some lines but beyond 3000 /4000 words, It breaks giving the following error:

> call-stack-has-exceeded-maximum-of-depth-of-100

Here is the function that I am using:
[Function to split text](http://help.interfaceware.com/kb/1079)

What shall be done to fix this? I am on windows 8. Does it depend on the stack size of machine(windows 8 in my case) or the depth of recursive calls allowed by the software Iguana?

Any fix?

Comment: Edit your question and add your code (and the "lua" tag since the code seems written in Lua).

Comment: The implementation you cite seems to use tail calls for all recursion, so it should not consume stack. Did you modify it? Does Iguana break tail recursion in Lua?

Comment: No, I have not modified it at all. It's being used as it is. I am not sure of Iguana's behaviour with Tail recursion though

Comment: Try this in Iguana to see if tail recursion works: `function deep (x, y) if x <= 0 then return y else return deep (x - 1, y + 1) end end; deep(20000,0)` -- it should not get a stack error.

Comment: @DougCurrie: Oh, It still gave the stack error,  I just tried it in Iguana which definitely means that Iguana it is breaking tail recursion. What could be the possible fixes for this?

Comment: Maximum allowed is 99 only, It infact breaks at 100.

Comment: Since the code you are using is tail recursive, you can fix it using goto if Iguana provides it. Instead of the recursive call, set all the arguments and goto a new label at the start of the function. If Iguana does not have goto, you will have to turn each of the recursive functions into a loop.